# Count number of rows based in a pattern on a column

Tags: awk, libreoffice-calc

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
pdbid   ch  spacegroup  ph  uniprotacc  name
5TUE    A   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUE    B   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUF    A   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUF    B   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUI    A   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUI    B   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
6J3M    A   F 41 3 2        A0A059ZFC5  Phosphopantetheine adenylyltransferase
6JNH    A   F 41 3 2        A0A059ZFC5  Phosphopantetheine adenylyltransferase
6JOG    A   F 41 3 2    5.6 A0A059ZFC5  Phosphopantetheine adenylyltransferase
4BRZ    A   P 1 21 1    7   A0A067XG63  HALOALKANE DEHALOGENASE
4BRZ    B   P 1 21 1    7   A0A067XG63  HALOALKANE DEHALOGENASE
4C6H    A   P 21 21 2       A0A067XG66  HALOALKANE DEHALOGENASE
```

I want to count every entry, based on column 5 (uniprotacc). Output should be something like this

```
pdbid   ch  spacegroup  ph  uniprotacc  newval  name
5TUE    A   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  1   Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUE    B   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  2   Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUF    A   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  3   Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUF    B   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  4   Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUI    A   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  5   Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUI    B   P 21 21 21      A0A059WYP6  6   Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
6J3M    A   F 41 3 2        A0A059ZFC5  1   Phosphopantetheine adenylyltransferase
6JNH    A   F 41 3 2        A0A059ZFC5  2   Phosphopantetheine adenylyltransferase
6JOG    A   F 41 3 2    5.6 A0A059ZFC5  3   Phosphopantetheine adenylyltransferase
4BRZ    A   P 1 21 1    7   A0A067XG63  1   HALOALKANE DEHALOGENASE
4BRZ    B   P 1 21 1    7   A0A067XG63  2   HALOALKANE DEHALOGENASE
4C6H    A   P 21 21 2       A0A067XG66  1   HALOALKANE DEHALOGENASE
```

I do not know, I think maybe awk or even libreoffice-calc can do the job easily. But any help is appreciated.

File is a `tsv` meaning tab separated file.

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us at all. Use textual examples instead

Comment: Of course. I copy the data from libreoffice-calc but somehow stackoverflow change it into an image. Whole dataset is here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ga6EV2kgqDNEMXcXthCo7yEOwuSWTdM8

Comment: @murpholinox, kindly post data only in text format though we understand your concern that somehow data is changing to images(not sure how) but seeing samples in images is very painful for people who are seeing this question so for good quality of question kindly try to post it in text format only, cheers.

Comment: Done. I am very sorry.

Comment: @murpholinox, you need not to be sorry we all learn here, cheers and thanks again for changing your samples to text.

Comment: Is your `A0` column is fixed I mean value vice? Of you may have other than A0 values too? Because I am seeing that your column 7 is NOT fixed then how come we are going to figure out which column index should be counted? Kindly elaborate more on same.

Comment: Column five is a unitprot accession code, meaning a string 6 to 10 characters long with numbers and letters. The last 3 rows in the whole dataset do not contain a uniprot accession code but I think I can live with that.

Comment: Is your file sorted on that column already like your sample?

Comment: @murpholinox, Sorry but your question is still not clear, please do add more details to it and let us know then on same.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}(FNR==1){$5=$5 OFS "newval"; print; next}{$5=$5 OFS (++a[$5])}1' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an `awk` script solution.

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
NR==1 {$NF = "newval" OFS $NF}
NR>1 {$NF = ++seen[$(NF - 1)] OFS $NF}
1
```

#### running:

```
awk -f script.awk input.tsv
```

#### output:

```
pdbid   ch      spacegroup              ph      uniprotacc      newval  name
5TUE    A       P 21 21 21              A0A059WYP6      1       Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUE    B       P 21 21 21              A0A059WYP6      2       Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUF    A       P 21 21 21              A0A059WYP6      3       Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUF    B       P 21 21 21              A0A059WYP6      4       Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUI    A       P 21 21 21              A0A059WYP6      5       Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
5TUI    B       P 21 21 21              A0A059WYP6      6       Tetracycline destructase Tet(50)
6J3M    A       F 41 3 2                A0A059ZFC5      1       Phosphopantetheine adenylyltransferase
6JNH    A       F 41 3 2                A0A059ZFC5      2       Phosphopantetheine adenylyltransferase
6JOG    A       F 41 3 2        5.6     A0A059ZFC5      3       Phosphopantetheine adenylyltransferase
4BRZ    A       P 1 21 1        7       A0A067XG63      1       HALOALKANE DEHALOGENASE
4BRZ    B       P 1 21 1        7       A0A067XG63      2       HALOALKANE DEHALOGENASE
4C6H    A       P 21 21 2               A0A067XG66      1       HALOALKANE DEHALOGENASE
```

#### script explanation:

```
BEGIN { # pre processing 
    FS = "\t"; # assign input field separator to "\t" tab
    OFS = "\t"; # assign ouput field separator to "\t" tab
}
NR==1 { # processing first line
    # $NF is the last field in input line
    $NF = "newval" OFS $NF; # prefix last field with "newval" and tab
}
NR>1 { # processing non first line
    # $(NF - 1) is the befroe last field in input line. Such as A0A059WYP6
    # seen[$(NF - 1)] is an array couning the occurance of $(NF - 1)
    # ++seen[$(NF - 1)] is an incremented array couning the occurance of $(NF - 1)
    $NF = ++seen[$(NF - 1)] OFS $NF; # prefix last field with an incremented array couning the occurance of $(NF - 1) and tab
}
{print} # print every processed line
```

Answer (score 1):

In Calc, put this formula in the second row of column `F` (the *newval* column) and drag down to fill.

```
=IF(E2=E1;F1+1;1)
```